# Dnspython: Setting query timeout/lifetime

Tags: python, timeout, lifetime, dnspython

I have a small script that checks a large list of domains for their MX records, everything works fine but when the script finds a domain with no record, it takes quite a long time to skip to the next one.

I have tried adding:

```
query.lifetime = 1.0
or
query.timeout = 1.0
```

but this doesn't seem to do anything. Does anyone know how this setting is configured?

My script is below, thanks for your time.

```
import dns.resolver
from dns.exception import DNSException
import dns.query
import csv

domains = csv.reader(open('domains.csv', 'rU'))
output = open('output.txt', 'w')
for row in domains:
    try:
        domain = row[0]
        query = dns.resolver.query(domain,'MX')
        query.lifetime = 1.0
    except DNSException:
        print "nothing here"
    for rdata in query:
            print domain, " ", rdata.exchange, 'has preference', rdata.preference
            output.writelines(domain)
            output.writelines(",")
            output.writelines(rdata.exchange.to_text())
            output.writelines("\n")
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You're setting the timeout *after* you've already performed the query. So that's not gonna do anything!

What you want to do instead is create a `Resolver` object, set *its* timeout, and then call its `query()` method. `dns.resolver.query()` is just a convenience function that instantiates a default `Resolver` object and invokes its `query()` method, so you need to do that manually if you don't want a default `Resolver`.

```
resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
resolver.timeout = 1
resolver.lifetime = 1
```

Then use this in your loop:

```
try:
    domain = row[0]
    query = resolver.resolve(domain,'MX')
except:
    # etc.
```

You should be able to use the same `Resolver` object for all queries.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not really sure what the difference is (never used that library) but I'm glad you found the right attribute.

Comment: Note that `timeout` is only half of the equation. As in OP's original example, `lifetime` should be used too. See http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.dnspython.user/144

Comment: @JameS : link dead. [official doc|http://www.dnspython.org/docs/1.14.0/dns.resolver.Resolver-class.html] 
"If the lifetime expires, a Timeout exception will occur." . I tested and yes .lifetime was enough to cancel search exception to catch : `dns.exception.Timeout`

Comment: [official doc](http://www.dnspython.org/docs/1.14.0/dns.resolver.Resolver-class.html). Meh, my link was ugly. After 5mins can't edit sorry for spam.

Comment: Brilliant! I had a hard time searching for this answer, but this is the answer!! :)

Comment: `query = resolver.query(domain,'MX')` should be `query = resolver.resolve(domain,'MX')` nowadays.